# How to make SonarQube honour javascript constructor function naming conventions

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have a very simple javascript constructor function that looks like this:

```
function DisplayedTableData() {
    this.rowData = [];
}
```

SonarQube is complaining about this and giving me the error, "Function names should comply with a naming convention", because it starts with a capital letter.

But it's a constructor - it's supposed to start with a capital letter!

Does anyone know a way to make SonarQube recognise that this is meant to be a constructor? Or a way to disable the rule in this particular case? Or an easy way to fix the rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On current moment the only options are:

1. Disable this rule at all
2. Change default format on something like:
   ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ (to allow either upper and lowercase letters)

It's possible that in future SQ will track JSDoc annotatations (but it's not the case for now):

```
    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    function MyClass() {
       this.foo = 'bar';
    }
```